# Modify readonly fields in CECIL

Tags: mono, mono.cecil

I have the below field declaration in one of my classes

```
private readonly string name = "some name";
```

How can I remove the 'readonly' in the assembly at run time using FieldDefinition or some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was in hurry to get this answer and tried myself later. So found that below property will do it

```
IsInitOnly
```